# How to compare a variable with a variable minus a constant in a linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to compare a variable with another variable minus a constant in a linux shell script.

In cpp this would look like this:

```
int index = x;
int max_num = y;

if (index < max_num - 1) {
  // do whatever
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

In the shell i tried the following:

```
  index=0
  max_num=2
  if [ $index -lt ($max_num - 1) ]; then
    sleep 20
  else 
    echo "NO SLEEP REQUIRED"
  fi
```

I also tried:

```
if [ $index -lt ($max_num-1) ]; then
...

if [ $index -lt $max_num - 1 ]; then
...

if [ $index -lt $max_num-1 ]; then
...
```

but non of these versions works. 
How do you write such a condition correctly?

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The various examples that you tried do not work because no arithmetic operation actually happens in any of the variants that you tried.

You could say:

```
if [[ $index -lt $((max_num-1)) ]]; then
  echo yes
fi
```

---

`$(( expression ))` denotes [Arithmetic Expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion).

`[[ expression ]]` is a [Conditional Construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs).

Comment: What is the significance of the double braces (both [[]] and (()))?

Answer (score 3):

Portably (plain `sh`), you could say

```
if [ "$index" -lt "$((max_num-1))" ]; then
    echo yes
fi
```

Short version

```
[ "$index" -lt "$((max_num-1))" ] && echo yes;
```

`[` is  the `test` program, but requires the closing `]` when called as `[`. Note the required quoting around variables. The quoting is not needed when using the redundant and inconsistent bash extensions cruft (`[[ ... ]]`).

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`, a more readable arithmetic command is available:

```
index=0
max_num=2
if (( index < max_num - 1 )); then
  sleep 20
else 
  echo "NO SLEEP REQUIRED"
fi
```

The strictly POSIX-compliant equivalent is

```
index=0
max_num=2
if [ "$index" -lt $((max_num - 1)) ]; then
  sleep 20
else 
  echo "NO SLEEP REQUIRED"
fi
```

Comment: `+1` for the perfect bash solution!